# Replace the vowels of user string input with another input character using functions

Tags: c++, string, function, input, character

I am writing a code that gets a string input from the user, then it gets a character input from the user. The string input will have all the vowels replaced with the character input and get printed out. One function is used to validate if the letter of the string is a vowel and the other function is to replace the vowel of the string with the given character from the user. The problem with my code is that I am unsure of why the functions cannot validate the string's vowels and replace them.

This is the output that I want:

```
Enter a string: Hello There
Enter a character: $
The new String is: H$ll$ Th$r$
```

This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void isVowel(string s);

void replaceV(char ch);

int main() {

  string s;

  char ch;

  cout << "Enter a string: "<< endl;

  getline(cin,s);

  cout<<"Enter a character: "<< endl;

  cin>> ch;

  replaceV(ch);
  
  return 0;
}

void isVowel(string s){

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){

    char ch = s[i];

    if (ch == 'A'||ch == 'E'||ch == 'I'||ch == 'O'||ch == 'U'||ch == 'a'||ch == 'e'||ch == 'i'||ch == 'o'||ch == 'u'){
      i++;
    }

}

void replaceV(char ch){


    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    isVowel(s);
    s[i] = ch;
    }

    cout << "The new string is " << s;

    }
}
```

Comment: your code has several errors. please include the error message in the question

Comment: 1. You need to check for both the uppercase and lowercase vowel characters. You are checking only for uppercase
2. You are just _calling_ `isVowel(s)` but not actually doing anything based on it.
3. You end up iterating the entire string _every time_ you check for `isVowel()` rather than just checking for whether `ch` is a vowel or not.

Please take some time to review the code, debug it and then seek help. These are **not subtle** errors.